# How to set display resolution via PowerShell on Win10 Pro

Tags: powershell, resolution, windows-10-pro

I was asked by a client's IT admin to "write a powershell script that sets the resolution manually on bootup". Presumably it is possible if they're asking me to do this. I have absolutely no experience with powershell. My scripts/commands and their errors are as follows:

```
Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768
```

`Set-DisplayResolution` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

```
Set-ScreenResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768
```

`Set-ScreenResolution` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

```
SetDisplayResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768
```

`SetDisplayResolution` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

What am I missing? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: [`Set-DisplayResolution`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servercore/set-displayresolution?view=win10-ps) is a commandlet from the [ServerCore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servercore/?view=win10-ps) PowerShell module and seems not to be available on Windows 10.

Comment: Can confirm what @CodeFox said. Running `Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768` on Windows Server 2019 worked out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where you got your example from but in a native powershell there is no command to set the resolution.

I use AutoHotKey. You can build your own script there or use [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375988/2089396) from the net.

Or you could write your own function, that can be called from powershell: [see here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2a631d72-206d-4036-a3f2-2e150f297515)

And of course there are several 3rd party tools depending on your requirements. Here's [one example](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2067039-w10-set-resolution-by-registry-cmd-powershell) that works with a script as well or here are [7 others](https://listoffreeware.com/free-screen-resolution-changer-software-windows/). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to have the resolution set automatically when the machine boots (I realize the resolution should persist through a power cycle and/or is hardware-dependent, but just accept this as presupposition for the given scenario).

Comment: @A__ how many screens?

Comment: How would that powershell function you linked be organized? Would I put that inside a ps1 script, followed by the actual call to it (`Set-ScreenResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768`) inside the script as well?

Comment: one 4k display ////

Comment: @A__ as shown in the paramter definition `param()` would have guessed `Set-ScreenResolution 1024 768` but I'm propable wrong since the script says in it's example it should be `Set-ScreenResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768`. Haven't used my own function in powershell for quite a while, I'm propable mistaken, just in case: try both! ;)

Comment: Thanks, the solution was to include that linked powershell function immediately followed by the call to it, with the `Set-ScreenResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768` syntax, in the ps1 file.

Answer (score 12):

You need to install the [DisplaySettings](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DisplaySettings/0.0.2) module from Powershell-Gallery to get this function.

### Module Installation

```
Install-Module -Name DisplaySettings
```

### Usage

```
Set-DisplayResolution -Width 800 -Height 600
```

Comment: Tried so many methods, this one works great!

Comment: This works greats with graphics modes that are reconised, but not with other graphics modes...  Is there a way to create a new `DisplayResolution`?

Answer (score 3):

Per [Albin's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1493365/892036):

Make a setResolution.ps1 file with the following contents (src):

```
Function Set-ScreenResolution { 

<# 
    .Synopsis 
        Sets the Screen Resolution of the primary monitor 
    .Description 
        Uses Pinvoke and ChangeDisplaySettings Win32API to make the change 
    .Example 
        Set-ScreenResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768         
    #> 
param ( 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
           Position = 0)] 
[int] 
$Width, 

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
           Position = 1)] 
[int] 
$Height 
) 

$pinvokeCode = @" 

using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace Resolution 
{ 

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
    public struct DEVMODE1 
    { 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] 
        public string dmDeviceName; 
        public short dmSpecVersion; 
        public short dmDriverVersion; 
        public short dmSize; 
        public short dmDriverExtra; 
        public int dmFields; 

        public short dmOrientation; 
        public short dmPaperSize; 
        public short dmPaperLength; 
        public short dmPaperWidth; 

        public short dmScale; 
        public short dmCopies; 
        public short dmDefaultSource; 
        public short dmPrintQuality; 
        public short dmColor; 
        public short dmDuplex; 
        public short dmYResolution; 
        public short dmTTOption; 
        public short dmCollate; 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] 
        public string dmFormName; 
        public short dmLogPixels; 
        public short dmBitsPerPel; 
        public int dmPelsWidth; 
        public int dmPelsHeight; 

        public int dmDisplayFlags; 
        public int dmDisplayFrequency; 

        public int dmICMMethod; 
        public int dmICMIntent; 
        public int dmMediaType; 
        public int dmDitherType; 
        public int dmReserved1; 
        public int dmReserved2; 

        public int dmPanningWidth; 
        public int dmPanningHeight; 
    }; 



    class User_32 
    { 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE1 devMode); 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE1 devMode, int flags); 

        public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1; 
        public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01; 
        public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1; 
    } 



    public class PrmaryScreenResolution 
    { 
        static public string ChangeResolution(int width, int height) 
        { 

            DEVMODE1 dm = GetDevMode1(); 

            if (0 != User_32.EnumDisplaySettings(null, User_32.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm)) 
            { 

                dm.dmPelsWidth = width; 
                dm.dmPelsHeight = height; 

                int iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_TEST); 

                if (iRet == User_32.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED) 
                { 
                    return "Unable To Process Your Request. Sorry For This Inconvenience."; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY); 
                    switch (iRet) 
                    { 
                        case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: 
                            { 
                                return "Success"; 
                            } 
                        case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_RESTART: 
                            { 
                                return "You Need To Reboot For The Change To Happen.\n If You Feel Any Problem After Rebooting Your Machine\nThen Try To Change Resolution In Safe Mode."; 
                            } 
                        default: 
                            { 
                                return "Failed To Change The Resolution"; 
                            } 
                    } 

                } 


            } 
            else 
            { 
                return "Failed To Change The Resolution."; 
            } 
        } 

        private static DEVMODE1 GetDevMode1() 
        { 
            DEVMODE1 dm = new DEVMODE1(); 
            dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm); 
            return dm; 
        } 
    } 
} 

"@ 

Add-Type $pinvokeCode -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
[Resolution.PrmaryScreenResolution]::ChangeResolution($width,$height) 
} 

Set-ScreenResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768
```

Then the file can be executed from powershell as follows

```
`C:\path-to-file\setResolution.ps1`
```

Answer (score 0):

The powershell script from Albin's post was working OK - but on one machine only let me set 1920x1080 and not 1920x1200 which I was able to do manually. In the end I had to use Nirsoft MultiMonitor which lets you save and load profiles. I was able to edit the config file and just put in the resolution parameters and it is working quite nicely. The config file looks like this :

```
Name=\\.\DISPLAY1
Width=1920
Height=1200
```

While I prefer to avoid third party tools where possible, on this occasion its free, lightweight and just works very well (and didn't complain about any virus)...

Comment: *Note: This may look like a spam but it isn't, I checked it.*